# How to make a cURL request , retrieve, and display in a single PHP file?

Tags: php, magento, curl, laravel, laravel-4

### Goals

- I have 2 sites : A and B
- Site A will need data from site B
- I want to make a cURL request to my other site and grab public data
- I want to retrieve those data, and display them in a nice format
- I want to `convert` the pieces of code that I had, into **ONE** php file

### Reason

- I want that because I can use this script in a CMS like Magento

### Here is what I've tried

- Originally, I used Laravel 4.0 this whole thing.
- I created a route filter, route to call my controller function that call my view

**Route Filter**

```
Route::filter('api', function() {

    if (Input::get('key') != '**********')
    {
        return Response::view('errors.404', array(), 404);
    }
});
```

**Route**

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function(){
    Route::get('url', array('before' => 'api', 'uses' => 'UrlController@index'));
    Route::get('url/decode', 'UrlController@decode');

});
```

**Controller function**

```
public function decode()
    {

        if( App::environment('dev') )
            $ch = curl_init("http://dev.d.biossusa.com/api/url?key=**********");
        elseif ( App::environment('local') ) 
            $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/api/url?key=**********");
        else 
            $ch = curl_init("http://d.biossusa.com/api/url?key=**********");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:**********");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $body = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        $distributors = json_decode($body, TRUE); 

        return View::make('jsons.decoding')->with('distributors', $distributors );  

    }
```

and it working. End result look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/01wxsasq/).

Now, I want to combine everything I have in to **ONE** php file, so I can re-use in a different places.

Can someone get me started based on what I have ?

Please kindly let me know, If there anything else that I can provide here.

If the `php` code is running, the end result should look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/01wxsasq/).

Comment: it's your own site... why make an api call to your own site when the "fetch" code would already be running within the same infrastructure and could just directly fetch it anyways? doing a full-blown http request to yourself is generally highly wasteful and redundant.

Comment: No. You misunderstand me, and maybe I wasn't clear enough. I have 2 sites. 1 site running on Magento, the site running on magento, need a data from my other site. This is very useful and import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try place this cURL request on top your **view**

```
<? php
        $ch = curl_init("http://d.biossusa.com/api/url?key=**********");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:**********");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $body = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $distributors = json_decode($body, TRUE);
```